# Setup apache fop for oracle apex

Tags: report, oracle-apex, apex, apache-fop

Does anybody have steps to set up Apache fop to use with oracle apex for report Printing purposes?

or anyone have another solution for Generating pdf and excel as per personalized format with oracle apex please suggest(Except Apex Office Print (AOP)).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 20.2 APEX includes native PDF and Excel export. If you want to have pixel-perfect reporting and you don't want to use AOP you can also have a look at [Dietmar Aust's Jasper Report APEX Integration](https://github.com/daust/JasperReportsIntegration) which should fulfill your requirement.

Apache FOP isn't supported anymore by ORDS/APEX.

Answer (score 0):

Apache FOP External is supported.
Please visit
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.2/aeadm/configuring-report-printing-for-an-instance.html#GUID-FA9105E7-396D-41FB-A8F2-06AA5F68F1D1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35323088)